# texlive lineo and fourier packages for CentOS 7?

Tags: texlive, installing, fourier

On a system recently installed with a fresh copy of CentOS 7, I attempted to compile some LaTeX documents and was met with missing LaTeX packages.  After installing some basic distributions using the standard CentOS package manager (`yum`), and still failing to find such things as `lineno.sty` and `fourier.sty`, I finally applied a sledgehammer:

```
yum install 'texlive-*'
```

Despite that this installed 536 packages, I am still missing `lineno.sty`. (I confirmed this with a `find / -name lineno.sty`.)  Googling suggests that it should be available in `texlive-collection-humanities`, but this package was not one of the 536 installed by the command above.  Indeed, `yum search humanities` reveals nothing in the standard repositories for CentOS 7.  In any case, whether `lineno.sty` is supposed to be in something named `texlive-colection-humanities` or not doesn't matter to me; I just want to find it (and the Fourier package).

How should I obtain it for CentOS 7?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.org suggest that it is in `texlive-humanities`. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: As I tried to explain, there is nothing with "humanities" in the name -- there is no `texlive-humanities`.  Also, this is about CentOS, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, in my experience the Ubuntu packages often point to the right name even on other systems, therefore I mentioned it. Anyway, there is always the option to download and install `lineno.sty` manually from CTAN.

Comment: The [advanced search at rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/2/simple/2) shows lineno.sty was in texlive-texmf-latex-2007-38.el6.noarch.rpm in CentOS 6.6, but is absent from 7. Either Daniel's or theswix's suggestions would be how I'd proceed from here.

Comment: `yum search lineno`?

Comment: `yum search lineno` on CentOS 7 produces `No matches found for: lineno`.

Comment: Install texlive manually, sicne what is delivered with CentOS is old. I came across [this package ](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/texlive/texlive-dummy/EnterpriseLinux-7?lang=en) which is a dummy to tell yum/your package manager that TexLive is installed so you don't have two versions of it.

Answer (score 2):

If CentOS provides a package with `lineno` in the name then

```
yum search lineno
```

should find it. For example, on Fedora, I get

```
Loaded plugins: filter-data, fs-snapshot, langpacks, list-data, post-transaction-actions, remove-with-leaves
=========================================================== N/S matched: lineno ===========================================================
linenoise-devel.i686 : Development files for linenoise
linenoise-devel.x86_64 : Development files for linenoise
texlive-lineno-doc.noarch : Documentation for lineno
linenoise.i686 : Minimal replacement for readline
linenoise.x86_64 : Minimal replacement for readline
texlive-lineno.noarch : Line numbers on paragraphs

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

However, if `lineno` is included in another package, this will not necessarily find it because `lineno` may not be mentioned explicitly in the description of the relevant package.

However, I cannot figure out how to ask `yum` to search for the package which provides a particular *file*.

On Arch Linux, for example, I can say

```
pkgfile lineno.sty
```

and get the response

```
extra/texlive-core
```

even though this package is not installed on my system. (I use upstream's TeX Live.)

But perhaps CentOS has a command of this kind such that you could ask it to tell you which package provides `lineno.sty`?